# How to perform some mathematical operation on some specific elements of a list using java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

#### Based on some conditions I want to perform some operation on a specific element of a list only.

I have a list of integers like this:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(30,33,29,0,34,0,45));
```

and I want to subtract 1 from each element EXCEPT 0.

I have tried some approaches like by applying the filter of Java 8 but it removed the zero values from the list.
I tried to apply other methods provided for streams API like `foreach() or .findFirst(),.findAny()` but it didn't work.

```
List<Integer> list2 = list.stream().filter(x -> x > 0).map(x -> x - 1).collect(Collectors.toList());
//list.stream().findFirst().ifPresent(x -> x - 1).collect(Collectors.toList()); //This is giving error
list.stream().forEach(x ->x.); //How to use this in this case
```

Actual   Result :    `[29,32,28,-1,33,-1,44]`

Expected Result :     `[29,32,28,0,33,0,44]`

Comment: "but it removed the zero values": it did that because you asked it to.

Comment: @Raedwald yes, actually I am not very much aware of the Java8 streams API usage that's why I tried some approaches by searching on to google but my intent is to generate that final list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list.stream()
    .map(x -> x == 0 ? x : x - 1)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Hi @Eugene, Thanks for the quick response. It is working. Just for more info on this, can we do this operation on the same list without creating another one, for e.g. by using .foreach() method.

Comment: @Vaibhav_Sharma not `forEach`, but you could use `replaceAll`

Answer (score 5):

In the example, you can use `Math.max` method:

```
list.stream()
    .map(x -> Math.max(0, x - 1))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In your case:

```
list.stream() // 1,2,0,5,0
    .filter(x -> x > 0) // 1,2,5
    .map(x -> x - 1) // 0,1,4
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // will return list with three elements [0,1,4]
```

Comment: Hi, The second one is not working because it is removing the 0's from the list that I don't want. But your first solution is working for me :) so thanks

Comment: I've just explained what is done in each step in your solution.

Comment: Just to note `Math.max(0, x - 1)` would not work for negative integers input.

Comment: and neither would the  `.filter(x -> x > 0)` work for the sample in the question. notice 0 is to be considered in the output.

Answer (score 2):

A non-stream version is using of `replaceAll`

```
list.replaceAll(x -> x != 0 ? x - 1 : x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution :

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size())
         .map(e -> list.get(e) == 0 ? list.get(e) : list.get(e) - 1)
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output :

> 29 32 28 0 33 0 44